# Syntax for projection in SQL

Tags: sql, select, projection

What is the difference, in terms of syntax, between selection (SELECT) and projection in SQL? I know that the first isolates rows and the second columns, but I don't know how to actually get a new table with the specified columns. What is the syntax for a projection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The projection corresponds to the columns you select, the selection to the filter you define in your where clause:

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PRICE > 100;
```

Here the projection corresponds to the ID and NAME columns whereas the selection corresponds to the price filter

Answer (score 1):

**Projection**, according to this [Article](http://www.marc-grange.net/SQL1_en.htm) 'is selecting the name of the columns of table(s) which one wishes to see appearing in the answer'.

Example (removed a previous example that may have been confusing)

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM [Table1]
```

**Selection**, uses WHERE Clauses to reduce the resultset and doesnt say anything about filtering columns.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE [Col1] = 'Result'
```

In SQL,these can be used in combination, ie. WHERE Clause and with filtering Columns;

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM [Table1] WHERE [Col1] = 'Result'
```

Regards,